# Why does Sofia Vergara have an accent?

Tags: analysis, modern-family

Is that Sofia Vergara's original accent or is she doing it for the sake of playing the *Colombian* character Gloria?

Comment: The `character-analysis` tag isn't really justified when the question is about a mere actor and not an actual character, is it? If there is at least some connection to a particular character played by her, it might be quite helpful to *name this movie or show*.

Comment: @Christian Rau - added the show tag. This accent is exagerated; I've seen her in other stuff on TV, and in a very early movie of hers - Big Trouble. Her other character accents can be suppressed, understated, or non-existent. She's ACTING!

Comment: Thanks for adding that tag I couldn't add a new tag so I didn't mention series name...

Comment: @wbogacz Thanks for adding the tag. Some additional thoughts on how this overacted accent might be relevant to the story and her character would make this question a really good one, in constrast to a trivial *"is she like her role in real life?"*-question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To [quote **Sofia Vergara**](http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20317432,00.html) herself:

> *"I go out to a mall or restaurant and when somebody hears me they'll go, 'Oh my God, it's your real accent'. I tell them, 'Yeah, I guess I'm not that good an actress!'"*
>
> Still, she admits, her comedic instincts may, at times, cause her to emphasize certain pronunciations
>
> *"I do make the accent a little stronger."*
>
> ***"I understand English; I read and write English perfectly, but the accent won't go away."***

[and:](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni25843122/)

> *"When I moved to L.A. and I wanted to act I did want to work on my accent... so I hired a speech coach. He was super-expensive."*
>
> *"(I spent) hours and hours, because it's not like you can do it one time a week; you have to do it, like, five times a week, three hours a day... It was the money most thrown away (sic). I got worse. Look at me now."*

(**Note:** Just like *Gloria*, the character she plays, *Sofia Vergara* [was born and raised](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005527/bio) in **Colombia**)